# EC2 external domain destination setup

Tags: php, admin

I am using  amazon EC2 and I'm in the process of creating a CMS. How would I do the following;

1. allow my clients to point their a-records to my elastic IP
2. manage domain destination settings so that each client's domain will point to a particular folder
3. I am using PHP, can this handle numbers 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a problem of web server rather PHP, webserver capable to handle virtual host would permit to host more than website on same server(point 2).

For the first point, you just have to give the elastic IP to your customer.

So, the short answer is 'yes' nothing to worry about.

Comment: which webserver do you recommend?  then how would i go about it?

Comment: Apache is most standard, so you have better to stick to it.

Comment: like this? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html but then i would need to restart the server everytime a person signs up

Comment: yep like this, not restart reload, you can reload the configuration.

Comment: i see,  can this all be done programmatically?  trying to figure out where to start

Comment: inside <VirtualHost> DocumentRoot points to the folder where the files are stored?